# Is there a rake task for advancing or retreating your schema version by exactly one?

Tags: version, rake, migrate

Back when migration version numbers were simply incremented as you created migrations, it was easy enough to do:

```
rake migrate VERSION=097
rake migrate VERSION=098
rake migrate VERSION=099
rake migrate VERSION=100
```

...but we now have migration numbers that are something like YYYYMMDDtimeofday.  Not that this is a bad thing - it keeps the migration version collisions to a minimum - but when I have 50 migrations and want to step through them one-at-a-time, it is a hassle:

```
rake migrate VERSION=20090129215142
rake migrate VERSION=20090129219783
```

...etc.  I have to have a list of all the migrations open in front of me, typing out the version numbers to advance by one.  Is there anything that would have an easier syntax, like:

```
rake migrate VERSION=NEXT
```

or

```
rake migrate VERSION=PREV
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You rollback to the previous migration with `rake db:rollback`. It doesn't look like you can go forward by only one migration though.

Answer (score 1):

You can also rollback to a very old version too.

> rake db:rollback VERSION=YYYYMMDDtimeofday